# How can I use different databases for different models

Tags: python, database, django

I have a model called `Requests` which I want to save in different database than default django databse.

The reason for this is that that table is going to record every request for `analytics` and that is going to get populated very heavily. As I am taking database backups hourly so I don't want to increase the db size just for that table.

So I was thinking of puting in separate DB so that I don't backup it up more often.

This docs says like this
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

```
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Reads go to a randomly-chosen slave.
    """
    return random.choice(['slave1', 'slave2'])

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Writes always go to master.
    """
    return 'master'
```

Now I am not sure how can I check that if my model is `Requests` then choose `database A` else `database B`

Answer (score 0):

Models are just classes - so check, if you have right class. This example should work for you:

```py
from analytics.models import Requests


def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Reads go to default database, unless it is about requests
    """
    if model is Requests:
        return 'database_A'
    else:
        return 'database_B'

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Writes go to default database, unless it is about requests
    """
    if model is Requests:
        return 'database_A'
    else:
        return 'database_B'
```

If you wish, though, you can also use one of some other techniques (such as checking `model.__name__` or looking at `model._meta`).

One note, though: the requests should not have foreign keys connecting them to models in other databases. But you probably already know that.

Comment: i tried `syncb --database=analytics` and i tried ouput the result and i get this  `raise Exception(model.__name__)
Exception: Permission` so i think model is something else not my Request Model

Comment: i tried that and it created all tables in my other database except the one i want

Comment: @fdsgds: Did you check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_syncdb ?